# Bootstrap Dropup not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The `dropup` in my `footer` is not working. When I change `dropup` to `dropdown`it starts to work as a `dropdown` but I need a `dropup`.
I followed bootstrap's guidelines but it's not working.
Here is the code

```
<footer id="cartFooter">
    <div class="row dropup">
        <button class="btn footerDropup dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>PHONE<span class="text-right">$99.99</span></li>
            <li>PLAN</li>
            <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
            <li>BUNDLE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row cartInfo">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> CART</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
            <p>$99.99</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
            <p><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Here is the css

```
    #cartFooter{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    background:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cartInfo{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.footerDropup{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212121!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.footerDropup:hover{
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #fff!important;
}

.footerDropup:visited{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Heres a link to the code pen
http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/KdqNpj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, run the code snippet to see the result

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The code</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link media="all" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style type="text/css">
#cartFooter{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    background:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cartInfo{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#divDropup{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
#divDropup button{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212121!important; 
    color: #fff!important;   
}

#divDropup ul{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212121!important; 
    color: #fff!important; 
    text-align: center;
}
        </style>
    <body>
        <div class="dropup" id="divDropup">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                    <li>PHONE<span class="text-right">$99.99</span></li>
                    <li>PLAN</li>
                    <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
                    <li>BUNDLE</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer id="cartFooter">        
            <div class="row cartInfo">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> CART</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <p>$99.99</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                    <p><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```